# Unable to Bind DataGridView upon SelectionChanged of ConboBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview

I have a DataGridView and is initially filled with the data.

I have ConboBox too and want that when selection is changed then DataGridView is also changed.

But *when selection is changed, gridview becomes empty*

```
 private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=medical;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
        con.Open();
           SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM medicines WHERE itemID = 4", con);
           dataGridView1.DataSource = da.Fill(ds);
           dataGridView1.Update();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check below line

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = da.Fill(ds);
```

It should be

```
da.Fill(ds); 
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```